# Error initializing MPSNNGraph

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I have built out a graph with convolutional, pooling, and concatenation layers. When I try to initialize the graph:

```
if let graph = MPSNNGraph(device: commandQueue.device,
                              resultImage: conv23.resultImage) {
        self.graph = graph
    } else {
        fatalError("Error: could not initialize graph")
}
```

I get the following error on the first part of the if statement with MPSNNGraph (it doesn't even go down to the fatalError part):

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1089b8070)
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Any error message in console when it crashes?

Comment: No, nothing in the console.

Comment: It might be one of your data sources. I would suggest reducing the graph to a single layer, and see if it still happens there. Then keep adding layers until the crash occurs.

Comment: I found that it crashed after the 20th convolutional layer. How do I find the error in the data source?

Comment: I found the error. I had flipped data source 20 and 21. I loaded the weights for the convolutional layer of 21 into 20 and vice versa. Thanks for the help!